# How to auto save passwords in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, passwords, ubuntu-11.04

Whenever I log in to Gmail or Facebook, Firefox ask whether to 'Remember password'. I am looking for add ons /  plugin for Firefox which will do this but is it possible to set up Firefox to auto save my passwords for sites without each time asking me 'Remember password' ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/958529) says:

> this isn't possible with the built-in options in firefox due to the security implications this would entail.

Answer (score 1):

There is an add-on: Aptly named [Remember Passwords](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/remember-passwords/).  Another recommendation I saw a couple of times is [Saved Password Editor](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/saved-password-editor/) ... it doesn't seem so obvious at first glance but the first review speaks of these limitations too.

Comment: These tools asking me the options **Remember passwords**, **Never for this site**, **Not now**. I don,t like this. It should _Remember Passwords_ without asking me.